# How I can run CMD commands as administrator with powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to run CMD commands as admin with Powershell. There is full command list:

```
Dism /OnLine /CleanUp-Image /CheckHealth&Dism /OnLine /CleanUp-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Can be any way to do this? I want to do with Run command.

Answer (score 0):

You can run most `cmd` commands within PowerShell without having to open another process, but if you want to elevate you will need to invoke `Start-Process -RunAs` to elevate the child process. For example:

```
$spArgs = @{
  Verb = 'RunAs';
  Path = "${env:SystemRoot}\system32\dism.exe";
  ArgumentList = "/OnLine /CleanUp-Image /CheckHealth&Dism /OnLine /CleanUp-Image /RestoreHealth";
}
Start-Process @spArgs
```

---

If you want to run a `cmd` built-in command however, there's no external command you can run from PowerShell (for example, `mklink`). In this case you will need to run `cmd.exe` elevated powershell. To use the `mklink` example:

```
$spArgs = @{
  Verb = 'RunAs';
  Path = "${env:SystemRoot}\system32\cmd.exe";
  ArgumentList = "/c mklink /D LINK_PATH TARGET_PATH;
}
Start-Process @spArgs
```

---

In either scenario, if you want to run something elevated from something *other* than PowerShell, the commands above can be used though you will need to first proxy the call through `powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process ...."`

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Open the Command Prompt, and type the PowerShell as a command, then press Enter key. Step 2: Now, the command prompt will turn to Windows PowerShell. Step 3: Type the command start-process PowerShell -verb runas and press "enter" key. Step 4: It will bring up an elevated Windows PowerShell as an administrator.

Is that what you needed?